# Display a GIF image before loading the drop down list using jQuery and AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax, drop-down-menu

I was trying to load the "loader.gif" image before displaying the drop down list using the beforeSend function but it is not working, it is directly displaying the drop down list but not the gif file. I have no idea where I went wrong in my code.

```
function showcity(sel)
{
    var state_id=sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
    if(state_id.length > 0)
    {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url :'showcity.php',
            data: {'state_id':state_id},
            cache: false,
            beforeSend: function() {
                 $('#y').html('<img src="loader2.gif" alt="" width="24" height="24">');
                                },
            success:function(html){
                $("#y").html(html);
            }
        });
    }
}
<form>
<strong>State</strong><select name="state" onchange="showcity(this)">

    <option value="">Select State</option>

    <?php  if(mysql_num_rows($states) > 0) {  ?>
    <?php  while($st=mysql_fetch_array($states)) { ?>

    <option value="<?php echo $st['id']; ?>"><?php echo $st['state_name']; ?>

    <?php  }  ?>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
</form>
```

Comment: Console errors?

Comment: no. actually i have linked three dd lists when i select the first the second one displays but before displaying the dd list i want to load the  gif image as to show the process image but it is directly displaying the dd list.

Comment: Could you post HTML code as well?